# How to remove atmosphere broadcaster

Tags: java, websocket, atmosphere

Need your suggestion, please.
My system is about client program and web service. Clients are instantiators of some events, they send message to web service, it is processed and when done- broadcasted back. What I need to do is to close web-socket connection on server side, and cleanup resources. Right now, when I shutdown jetty I can see that all broadcasters are removed only at that step. If I send 10 messages with one client I get 10 broadcasters hanging on web service. Tryed .destroy() on broadcaster, but didn't really saw it working, tried also to destroy connection on client side, but also no success.

My subscribe is:

```
@GET
@Suspend
public SuspendResponse<String> subscribe(){
....
Broadcaster broadcaster = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().get("/"+path+"/"+id);

            ...somecallback here....
                        @Override
                        public void onMessage(String message) {
                             broadcaster.broadcast(message);
                             //here I want to destroy broadcaster and cleanup resources.
                        }

    return new SuspendResponse.SuspendResponseBuilder<String>()
        .broadcaster(broadcaster)
        .outputComments(true)
        .build();
}
```

I think, this approach can be also wrong, and there is other way to make things work.
Any ideas? Thank's!

Comment: Hm, I suppose, I need to trigger some onDestroy callback from client  but I can't understand how to do this,  any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following web/application.xml element

```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterLifeCyclePolicy</param-name>
      <param-value>IDLE_DESTROY</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

See the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Understanding-Broadcaster) for more info.

Comment: Tried this now, no results. Still looks the same. I' thinking now that something wrong is in design, I should not create so much resources per each request creating broadcaster.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the policy EMPTY_DESTROY, which will remove broadcaster if there are no AtmosphereResource associated with this broadcaster.

You can configure it in web.xml as mentioned by @jfarcand or programmatically as shown below

```
Broadcaster b = broadcasterFactory.get();
b.setBroadcasterLifeCyclePolicy(BroadcasterLifeCyclePolicy.EMPTY_DESTROY);
```